# Yii2 passing data from 3 Gridview to DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have in one page echo of 3 different gridview based on 3 different models. Models have no connection.
I want to collect some particular data from each grid with chechbox and send them in same DB tables. 
This is the display page:

```
/** Operators Grid View  **/ 
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    [ 'attribute' => 'useralias',
                    'label' =>'Operator Name',],

                    [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',],

                    [ 'attribute' => 'currency',
                    'label' =>'Operator Currency',],

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view}'],
                    ],
]); ?>

    /** Country Grid View  **/
     <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderCountry,
    'filterModel' => $searchModelCountry,
    'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',],


                    [ 'attribute' => 'popis',
                    'label' =>'Country',],

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view}'],
                    ],
]); ?>
    /** Currency Grid View  **/

     <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderCurrency,
    'filterModel' => $searchModelCurrency,
    'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    [ 'attribute' => 'currency_name',
                    'label' =>'Currency Name',],
                    [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',], 


                    [ 'attribute' => 'value',
                    'label' =>'Value',],

                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view}'],
                    ],
]); ?>
```

This is index function from controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
            //RMS
    $searchModel = new CardrmsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            //Country
            $searchModelCountry = new CountrySearch();
    $dataProviderCountry = $searchModelCountry->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            //Currency      
            $searchModelCurrency = new CurrencySearch();
    $dataProviderCurrency = $searchModelCurrency->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'searchModelCountry' => $searchModelCountry,
        'dataProviderCountry' => $dataProviderCountry,
                    'searchModelCurrency' => $searchModelCurrency,
        'dataProviderCurrency' => $dataProviderCurrency,
    ]);    }
```

I can't find anything for this, my idea was to create one action for collecting the data, but I dont know how to colect the data from all 3 selected checkbox in one step!
Plz any tips how it can be done?

Comment: GridView is a view for listing records. Where is your code that try to collect data? Post some screen shot may help us to understand the issue.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b4lxg2

Comment: As you see in link you have all data and after press on button I  want to insert selected data into one DB table to use them for next algorithm.

Comment: You can put all 3 GridView into a form with that button. `<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
3 GridView here.  BUTTON HERE.
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>` If you chose some records, you can get them from index page.

Comment: I moved it to form, but still don't get how the function off button should look like to collect all data from all views? can you give same example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first wrap your grids in active form. than set name for checkboxes in every grid

```
[ 
  'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
  'name'=>'anyname'

],
```

set form action where ever you want

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => 'your-action'
    ]);
```

dump and see the POST data in that action, you will get array of ids representing to selected row for each grid.
You can differentiate the data by name of checkbox in each grid.

Comment: Tx a lot i will try to do this.